# Javascript input.value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Domready.js library as an alternative to the jQuery `document.ready()` function and inside the ready function I have this code:

```
DomReady.ready( function() {

    /*
        DOM elements
    */ 
    var tel_input = document.getElementsByClassName( 'tel-input' );

    /*
        When .tel-input is focused, `06` should be added automatically
    */
    tel_input.onfocus = function() {
        tel_input.value = '06';
    };

});
```

This code doesn't do anything and the console doesn't throw an error. When putting an alert in the `tel_input.onfocus = function() {` it works, but inserting a value when the input is focused doesn't do anything.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` (element**s**, plural) returns a list of DOM elements, even if there is only one.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)  is always useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Frédéric Hamidi said in the comment - `getElementsByClassName` return a list of DOM elements.

You only have one element but you still have to get the first element of the list

```js
$( function() {

    /*
        DOM elements
    */ 
    var tel_input = document.getElementsByClassName( 'tel-input' );
    /*
        When .tel-input is focused, `06` should be added automatically
    */
    tel_input[0].onfocus = function() {
        tel_input[0].value = '06';
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="tel-input" />
```